# Android Soft Keyboard Pushing Controls Up Titanium

Tags: android, titanium, textfield, titanium-mobile

I can't seem to figure out why the appearance of the soft keyboard whilst editing a text field on Android causes some of my controls to get pushed up the page. Is there a way to stop a view or a button from being moved up? It makes a real mess!

code:

```
registration = {};
registration.view = Titanium.UI.createView({
top : 0,
backgroundImage : GetfilePath + 'bg.png',
});

registration.init = function(view, name) {
 var Scrolview = Titanium.UI.createScrollView({
    top : viewTop,
    height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
    layout : 'vertical',
    scrollType : 'vertical',
    showHorizontalScrollIndicator : false
});
registration.view.add(Scrolview);

var profileView = Ti.UI.createView({
    top : 10,
    height : 100,
    width : 100,
    //backgroundColor : 'red',
});

Scrolview.add(profileView);

var profileImage = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image : GetfilePath + 'ProfilePicIcon.png',
});

profileView.add(profileImage);

var chooseprofileView = Ti.UI.createView({
    top : 8,
    width : deviceName == 'tab' ? '92.5%' : '92.5%',
    height : deviceName == 'tab' ? 75 : 60,

});

Scrolview.add(chooseprofileView);

var chooseprofileImage = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundImage : GetfilePath + 'ChooseProfilebutton.png'
});

chooseprofileView.add(chooseprofileImage);

var chooseprofileLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text : 'Choose Profile Pic ',
    color : '#E6E6E6',
    font : {
        fontSize : deviceName == 'tab' ? 19 : 17,
        //fontWeight : 'bold',
        fontFamily : os({
            iphone : 'Helvetica Neue',
            ipad : 'Helvetica Neue',
            ipod : 'Helvetica Neue',
            android : 'helveticaneue-webfont'
        })
    },
});

chooseprofileImage.add(chooseprofileLabel);

//alert(UserDetailsInfoData[0].UserName);

var namesurnametextfield = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    borderStyle : Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
    hintText : 'Name & Surname*',
    backgroundColor : '#32302D',
    color : 'white',
    backgroundImage : 'none',
    keyboardToolbarHeight : 30,
    borderRadius : 10,
    borderColor : '#3F4246',
    borderWidth : 2,
    paddingLeft : 10,
    width : '90%',
    height : 55,
    top : '1%',

    //backgroundColor:'green'
});

Scrolview.add(namesurnametextfield);

var emailtextfield = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    borderStyle : Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
    hintText : 'Email Address*',
    backgroundColor : '#32302D',
    color : 'white',
    backgroundImage : 'none',
    keyboardToolbarHeight : 30,
    borderRadius : 10,
    paddingLeft : 10,
    borderColor : '#3F4246',
    borderWidth : 2,
    width : '90%',
    height : 55,
    top : '1%',
});

Scrolview.add(emailtextfield);

var cellnotextfield = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    borderStyle : Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
    hintText : 'Cellphone Number',
    backgroundColor : '#32302D',
    color : 'white',
    backgroundImage : 'none',
    keyboardToolbarHeight : 30,
    borderColor : '#3F4246',
    borderWidth : 2,
    borderRadius : 10,
    paddingLeft : 10,
    width : '90%',
    height : 55,
    top : '1%',
    keyboardType : Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_NUMBER_PAD,
});

Scrolview.add(cellnotextfield);

//alert(UserDetailsInfoData[0].UserName);

var displaynametextfield = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    borderStyle : Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
    hintText : 'Display Name*',
    backgroundColor : '#32302D',
    color : 'white',
    backgroundImage : 'none',
    keyboardToolbarHeight : 30,
    borderRadius : 10,
    borderColor : '#3F4246',
    borderWidth : 2,
    paddingLeft : 10,
    width : '90%',
    height : 55,
    top : '1%'
});

Scrolview.add(displaynametextfield);

};
```

i followed this [link](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/128861/android-soft-keyboard-pushing-controls-up) but the problem remains same.

```
ANY Solution?
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

In your `tiapp.xml` file under android tag add this line of code :

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" . . . >
```

One of the group of soft input visibility constants, `SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN, SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE, SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN, SOFT_INPUT_STATE_UNSPECIFIED, or SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE`.

One of the group of soft input adjustment constants, `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_UNSPECIFIED, SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE, or SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN.`

Also, check this :

- [Titanium windowSoftInputMode](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-property-windowSoftInputMode)
- [Android windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)

Sample Android example [here](http://blog.vogella.com/2010/10/25/android-windowsoftinputmode/)

Comment: thanks for looking my problem as i can see the this is already set in tiapp.xml  <activity
                    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
                    android:label="@string/app_name"
                    android:name="PhotoGap" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"/>

Comment: Links need updating: https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-property-windowSoftInputMode

Answer (score 1):

I have never tried titanium before, however in normal Java android development. we add this code to the manifest under the related activity tag.

```
<activity
android:name="Your-activity-name"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
...
```

I read that there is a Custom AndroidManifest.xml in Titanuim 3.x..
Hope this works for you.

Comment: i tried out this code but the problem remains same <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"> </activity>
                 <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> </activity>